# How do I get Java Spring Boot @transactional to work with rollbacks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the **@transactional** feature from **Spring Boot** for rollbacks.

I have a controller that calls a method which has a few sub methods it calls before inserting records into db. I'm putting the `**@transactional**` declaration above a parent method like the *sudo codebelow*.

My expectation is that the db inserts from `processAB()` method (*sudo code below*) would be reverted upon exception.

```
//controller
public StuffEntity<List<string>> processLogic(param1, param2){
   parentMethod(param1,param2);
}

@Transactional
private void parentMethod(Date processD, String processS){
   // some business logic code
   processE(processD, processS);
}

private void processE(Date processingD, String processingS){
   // additional business logic 
   try{
     if(noProcessErrors){
   handleSuccess(a, b);
   }else{
   // handles error
   handleProcessErrors(a,b);
   }catch (Exception e){
   Log(e);}
}

public void handleSuccess(a,b) throws CustomException {
   // success logic
   processAB();
}

public void processAB() throws CustomException {
   // update db
   throw exception;  // for test
}
```

Comment: `@Transactional` on `private` methods has no effect. Good reading here https://codete.com/blog/5-common-spring-transactional-pitfalls .

Comment: In addition, `@Transactional` already rollback if an exception is thrown through the transaction proxy. There is actually a parameter to **not** rollback, but this is not the default behavior.